# Associate select value to ngModel in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, select

I'm using Angular4 tyring to associate ngValue to ngModel but getting `Null`. So kindly help me to connect `ngValue` to `ngModel`

```html
<select name="gender" [(ngModel)]="nameForm.gender">
  <option [ngValue]="Male">Male</option>
  <option [ngValue]="Female">Female</option>
  <option [ngValue]="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

wrap around single quates `'Male'`

```
<select name="gender" [(ngModel)]="nameForm.gender">
    <option [ngValue]="'Male'">Male</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'Female'">Female</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'Others'">Others</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers - I would populate options via *ngFor:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of genders" [ngValue]="item">{{ item }}</option>
```

And in the component's class simply create genders property like this:

```
genders: string[] = ['Male', 'Female', 'Others'];
```

If you want to use different key-value, you can create object array:

```
[{value: 'male', title: 'Male'}, {value: 'female', title: 'Female'}, ...]
```

And in your template:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of genders" [ngValue]="item.value">{{ item.title }}</option>
```

Last case - if you want to have options in your template, you can simplify binding syntax:

```
<option ngValue="Male">Male</option>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to `value` attr directly:

```
<option [value]="'Male'">Male</option>
```

...note the single quotes inside `[value]`.

Answer (score 0):

use `[value]`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="nameForm.gender">
    <option [value]="'Male'">Male</option>
    <option [value]="'Female'">Female</option>
    <option [value]="'Others'">Others</option>
</select>
```